# how to dump all the variables into a file for later use?

Tags: python

I'd like to separate data and plot into different jupyter notebook since both of them takes a long time to create. so I am thinking to dump all the variables into a file, then load all the variables for plotting in another jupyter notebook.

I came across this link to use shelve module but I got an error. anyone have a better idea? Thanks

https://coderedirect.com/questions/79972/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session

```
import shelve

T='Hiya'
val=[1,2,3]

filename='./shelve.out'
my_shelf = shelve.open(filename,'n') # 'n' for new

for key in dir():
    try:
        my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
    except TypeError:
        #
        # __builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules can not be shelved.
        #
        print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
my_shelf.close()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR shelving: Out
ERROR shelving: _49
ERROR shelving: __builtin__
ERROR shelving: __builtins__
ERROR shelving: _oh
ERROR shelving: cm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-691557e10696> in <module>
      9 for key in dir():
     10     try:
---> 11         my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
     12     except TypeError:
     13         #

~\miniconda3\envs\tf_cpu\lib\shelve.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    122         f = BytesIO()
    123         p = Pickler(f, self._protocol)
--> 124         p.dump(value)
    125         self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue()
    126 

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000019714E44670>: attribute lookup <lambda> on jupyter_client.session failed
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it is corrected now

Comment: Instead of storing variables you can actually call that particular python program into other python program using sub process & thereby you can use that variables in called program.

Comment: You're getting a permission error because you're trying to write to the root directory `/`. Try writing to `/tmp` or your home directory.

Comment: Thanks Matt,yes the error is gone, not I got another error, PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000019714E44670>: attribute lookup <lambda> on jupyter_client.session failed

Comment: I just updated the error in the post

Comment: do you *have* to dump *everything*?  Can't you just write your *data* do disk in some standard format (json or even csv, for example), and then load that same data back later?  As a bonus this will force you to define proper interfaces, which should help the coding ;)

Comment: " so I am thinking to dump all the variables into a file" You should rethink that approach. Instead, *you should explicitly* manage the data you want to persist.

Comment: yes I have to dump everything

Comment: No, you do not. Instead, you need to *organize your code* such that you explicitly manage the data you want to persist. As you've discovered just dumping "all variables" is going to include a lot of stuff *that you definitely don't want*. Stop thinking in terms of *variables*, think in terms of *data structures*

Comment: But if you really must use this approach, just catch the `PicklingError` along with the `TypeError`s, but this is really just a bad way to do anything

Comment: Thanks juanpa for your suggestion. I bascailly want to split one code file into multiple codes such that I can run multiple codes file simultaneously. Each code file will have same data, but different type of lots of plots.  Each set of plot take a long time to finish. with multiple code file running, I can see different plots simulataneous. If I just do it one file, I have to wait one set of plots to finish in order to run another sets of plots. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Did you consider applying multi-threading/processing to the code to overcome this?